# Safe to edit Core Services .app Bundles?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard

I want to modify (or delete and put a replacement in the User Template) a default preference in an app bundle in System/CoreServices.

I'm assuming future software updates will possibly overwrite these changes.  What other caveats should one be aware of?  Would there be a possible instability caused?  This change would be deployed to lots of machines.

Comment: You're not actually editing CoreServices bundles by changing their related `defaults` in `~/Library/Preferences` for your users. Could you explain again what it is you want to do?

Comment: /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/default.plist is an example of a default preference inside an app bundle.  Just looking into what would happen if one was to muck with these files.

Comment: Are there any cases you would be unable to workaround by giving your users suitable preference files in `~/Library/Preferences`, such as (in your example), `com.apple.Dock.plist`?

Comment: After dealing with mac pref templates, I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: If it's only *preferences* defaults, those should just be copied over to the `~/Library/Preferences` directory, or used as template upon first launch. I suggest you provide your user accounts with sensible defaults and ask again once that approach fails. I think you won't be back with this issue ;) Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont beleive question cant be answered to the 100% with the information you give. I suggest you experiment to find out on a single mac, with a time machine backup before deploying. The effects it has depend completeley on the application and the canges you apply.

As far as my experience goes I've just modified the Dock application in order to alter how exposé looked by replacing two images in its resources. I suffered from no instability, but again, it was just 2 images.

About software update, it is possible that the changes are overwritten, but again, it depends on what you are modifying.

Why are you modifying CoreServices? I suggest other methods to achieve what you want to do, but if its the only way, Time Machine is your friend.